# Attach debugger as code behind from client and stop it in chrome dev-tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

There is a way to open the chrome debugger by code that is not available to the the user.(user don't see the debugger statement ...)
I mean if I put the command `debugger` and the I open the dev-tools and run the program it will stop at the debugger statement but my question is a bit different, let say that user have jsFiddle/JsBin etc and he have the ability to click on the line number of any statement(like below but from the client) and when he open the devtools it will stop on this line,
is it possible to attach this debugger?

something like this (line 54 & 58 )which happen from client

**[image: client]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is essentially a programmatic way of creating breakpoints.

I'm afraid this feature is not possible.

You can however use an extension along with [Chromes devtools API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) to force the developer tools to open right away, hence enabling all of your `debugger;` statements.

Comment: Thanks , so just to clarify you mean that there is no way to attach BP from client which will stop at the right statement in the dev tools(without using the "debugger")?

Comment: @shopia T, Correct.

Comment: 1+ , So do you know perhapes how cloud9 IDE did it for non-server(client) applications? very interesting  thing....

Comment: If you'll give me a link with an example, I think I'll be able to